# FEniCS CFD work-flow for complex geometries

Tags: fenics

I have COMSOL and the CFD package therein available, which provides me with an all-in-one solution for solving CFD problems. I have modeled and solved the geometry shown in the pictures below, which took me roughly one hour.

Now (just for kicks) I want to do the same in FEniCS and see how that goes. At this point, I am trying to establish an optimal work flow.

My approach at the moment is this:

1. create the geometry in [gmsh](http://geuz.org/gmsh/)
2. create the mesh in gmsh
3. import the mesh to dolfin using *dolfin-convert mesh_file.msh mesh_file.xml*
4. set-up boundary conditions in dolfin
5. solve navier-stokes equations
6. post-processing in ParaView

**Before** I start doing that, I would like to know if this work-flow is a good idea?!

Possible issues I see are setting up the boundary conditions from the imported gmsh mesh in dolfin, based on this [launchpad post](https://answers.launchpad.net/dolfin/+question/161172). I.e. is it better to define the boundary conditions in gmsh or in dolfin?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I've used](https://plus.google.com/110475963061639463862/posts/5NWw8dzrtst) this exact workflow for solving the Navier-Stokes equations in FEniCS.

Almost certainly the hardest part in the process will be implementing the numerical solution method; there is no out-of-the-box support for that in FEniCS (although of course all differential operators you need are available).
For reference, check out [nsbench](https://launchpad.net/nsbench), a Navier-Stokes benchmark suite written for FEniCS. It features a collection of common numerical solution methods and tests them against a number of example problems. Also check out [the FEniCS book](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/fenics-book), chapter 21. Depending on the Reynolds number of the flow you intent to simulate, you may need to stabilize the numerical solution with, e.g., [SUPG](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0045782582900718).

Comparing to COMSOL, using FEniCS for the task will definitely require a better understanding of the Navier-Stokes equations, numerical solution methods, and appropriate boundary conditions.

As for the specification of boundary conditions, I think `dolfin-convert` still doesn't carry over the tag information from Gmsh meshes to the dolfin format. If your domain isn't too complicated, manually re-tagging the boundaries in FEniCS  should be doable though.

Comment: thanks. I think publishing comparisons of FEniCS with COMSOL is sort of against the license agreement, so I will not go there (at least not in public) ;-)

Comment: According to comments in `meshconvert.py` it seems that both cell and facet markers are suported for gmsh for a pretty long time. If you also take this workflow seriously then it may be worth tweaking `meshconvert.py` for your needs.